# Copiar URL de un formulario completado de google forms para poder editarlo posteriormente desde una lista en pagina web

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Primero comentaros que soy totalmente nuevo, por lo que pido disculpas por errores de novato.
Busqué algo que me permitiera copiar la url del formulario de google forms una vez enviado para posteriormente, a través de una tabla (awesome table), pudiera seleccionarlo para editar la entrada, encontré este script de un usuario, lo compilo y ejecuto y da el siguiente error:

> 21:15:41  Error
> Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for FormApp.Form.getResponses.
> getEditResponseUrls @ Código.gs:27

Esta es la línea que da el error:

```
   var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
```

Aquí tenéis el codigo:

```
/*
 * Global Variables
 */

// Form URL
var formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1q5qW0YAORj-JgNXp0MS7ceOI6a2RfknDC3-8_1kEUUo/edit';
// Sheet name used as destination of the form responses
var sheetName = 'Respuestas de formulario 1';
/*
 * Name of the column to be used to hold the response edit URLs 
 * It should match exactly the header of the related column, 
 * otherwise it will do nothing.
 */
var columnName = 'URL' ;
// Responses starting row
var startRow = 2;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
  for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

Caso resuelto, me he dado cuenta que la variable startRow estaba erronea, ya que en la tabla comienzan los datos en startRow = 3, osea en la fila 3, ya que en la 2 tengo puesto los formatos stringfilter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Justo ayer publiqué una respuesta a una pregunta con cierta similitud en inglés... Aunque ya encontraste la solución para el caso específico del error, me parece apropiado compartir lo siguiente:

El problema de leer el *timestamp* en la hoja de cálculo de Google es que este tiene una precisión de segundos siendo que desde hace tiempo los formularios de Google internamente usan una precisión de milisegundos. Esto lo puedes comprobar usando [FormApp.FormResponse.getTimestamp()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)

Una solución algo riesgosa si esperas muchos usuarios que envíen respuestas de forma casi simultánea es obtener los timestamp y "redondear" el timestamp a segundos, pero seguramente será menos riesgos hacer la relación de las repuestas en la hoja de cálculo con las del formulario con base en el orden en que se encuentran, sólo asegúrate que en la hoja la hoja de cálculo le orden sea con base en el *timestamp* de forma ascendente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte. No creo que tenga problemas con Timespamp, la cantidad de usuarios será pequeña, y en principio no debería haber más de uno a cuatro usuarios activos por día, ya que la web es para un entorno laboral limitado.